# Update Cells in an In Memory Data table

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable, dataset

Ok, the story so far is i have a datatable, about 10,000 lines or so. and about 150 columns per row. ao more or less 150.000 cells in this datatable. i have all updateing working fine 
but the updating is slow. 
I need to iterate  through a list of porcedures then update cells in the table depending on the procedure. when i am completle finished updating about 75% - 80% of all the cells will have changed. 
I am using a search on the table using a primary key index assigened to an INT value.

datatable.rows.find() seems a a little quicker
datatable.select ( expression ) almost the same but little difference.

Is there any ideas who may speed this up. uppon changing 80,000 - 120,000 cells it can take minutes.

anyideas would be great thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A study in the March 2005 issue of ASP.Net Pro magazine compared various approaches involving `DataTables`, `DataViews` and `DataReaders`. Their findings were that **the fastest approach depended upon the number of records involved**.

For **50 records or less**, by far the fastest search method was a `For..Next` loop on the `DataTable's DataRowCollection`. That approach was followed by `DataRowCollection.Find`. Many times slower were re-retrieving the data with a `DataReader`, using `DataView.RowFilter`, and worst of all using `DataTable.Select`.

For **500 - 5,000 records**, the fastest search was with `DataRowCollection.Find`, followed closely by `DataTable.Select`. The worst by far for this range of records were `DataView.RowFilter` and `DataView.FindRows`.

For **50,000 records**, the fastest search was accomplished with `DataRowCollection.Find.` In a close second place was re-retrieving the records with a `DataReader`. The worst by far for this category were `DataView.RowFilter` and `DataView.FindRows.`

Comment: It turns out the issue was with the Datatable setter method , and it seems to be a common issue for people using large datatables. Great Info though. thanks